# Message encoder/decoder

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding a message encoder/decoder and am having trouble with the encode_message, decode_message, and get_cipher functions I'm not sure where I went wrong.I have also attached the instructions as comments. Also, if there is an easier way to code the characters for the alphabet array please add it to the answer as well.

```
'use strict()';

function bind_events() {
  'use strict';

  $('#encode_msg').hide();
  $('#decode_msg').hide();

  // bind the event handler to the event. 
  $('#encode_msg').click(function() {
    encode_handler();
  });

  $('#decode_msg').click(function() {
    decode_handler();
  });

  var $keyword = $('#keyword');
  $($keyword).blur(function() {
    $('#encode_msg').hide();
    $('#decode_msg').hide();
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $('#encode_msg').show();
      $('#decode_msg').show();
    } else {
      $('#encode_msg').hide();
      $('#decode_msg').hide();
    }

  });

}

function update_display(header, message) {
  'use strict';

  return $('#display-message h2, p').text();
}

function get_keyword() {
  'use strict';

  return $('#keyword').val().split('');;
}


function get_message() {
  'use strict';

  return $('#message').val().split('');
}

/**
 * Input:   None
 * Output:  The cipher alphabet using the keyword. 
 *              The cipher contains all characters from a to z, A to Z 
 *              and punctuation /.,;:?! 
 *              The order of the letters will be mixed up. 
 * Process:
 * 0. the alphabet as an array. 
 *      * The alphabet must include all upper and lower case letters 
 *      * AND the following punctuation (/.,?;:!) 
 * 1. Create a variable to hold the keyword from the form. 
 * 2. Declare a variable called remaining_letters and initialize it to the keyword.
 *      * The keyword should be split into an array.  
 *      * The variable will hold the remaining letters from the original alphabet  
 *      (the alphabet ordered a to z) that are not in the keyword.
 * 3. Iterate through the length of the alphabet. 
 *      3.1 Get the index of the alphabet letter from the keyword. 
 *      3.2 If the index value is less than 0, push the letter from the alphabet
 *              onto the remaining_letters array 
 * 4. Return remaining_letters      
 */
function get_cipher() {
  'use strict';
  var alphabet = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, '/', '.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!'];
  var $keyword = $('#keyword');
  var $remaining_letters = $keyword;
  $('$keyword').val().split('');

  for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
    if (alphabet[i] == $keyword[j]) {
      if (j < 0) {
        remaining_letters.push(alphabet[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return remaining_letters;

}


function encode_handler() {
  'use strict';
  var encoded_message = encode_message();
  update_display('Encoded Message', encoded_message);
}


function decode_handler() {
  'use strict';
  var decoded_message = decode_message();
  update_display('Decoded Message', decoded_message);
}

/**
 * Encode the message. 
 * Input:     None
 * Output:    The encrypted message.
 * Process:
 *        1. Required Variables:
 *            1. the cipher as an array
 *            2. the alphabet as an array. 
 *                * The alphabet must include all upper and lower case letters 
 *                * AND the following punctuation ( .,?;:!) - including the space
 *            3. the message from the form as an array
 *            4. an empty array variable that will hold the encoded message
 *     2. iterate through the length of the message.
 *         1. Find the index of the letter (message) in the alphabet.
 *         2. when the index value is positive (including 0) 
 *                 then get the corresponding letter from the cipher using the index
 *                 and push it onto the encoded message array.
 *             otherwise
 *                 push the letter (message) onto the encoded message array.
 *     3. return the encoded message array joined together.
 */
function encode_message() {
  'use strict';
  var cipher = [];
  var alphabet = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, '/', '.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!'];
  var message = get_message();
  var encoded_message = [];

  for (i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    if (message[i] == alphabet[j]) {
      if (j < 0) {
        encoded_message.push(message[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return encoded_message.toString();
}

/**
 * Input:    None
 * Output:   The decrypted message.
 * Process:
 *       1. Required Variables:
 *           1. the cipher as an array
 *           2. the alphabet as an array. 
 *           3. the message from the form as an array
 *           4. an empty array variable that will hold the decoded message
 *       2. iterate through the length of the message.
 *           1. Find the index of the letter (message) in the cipher.
 *           2. when the index value is positive (including 0) 
 *                   then get the corresponding letter from the alphabet using the index
 *                   and push it onto the decoded message array.
 *               otherwise
 *                   push the letter (message) onto the decoded message array.
 *       3. return the decoded message array joined together.
 */
function decode_message() {
  'use strict';
  var cipher = [];
  var alphabet = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, '/', '.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!'];
  var message = get_message();
  var decoded_message = [];
  for (i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    if (message[i] == alphabet[j]) {
      if (j < 0) {
        decoded_message.push(message[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return decoded_message.toString();
}

$(bind_events).ready();
```

How should I edit these functions so they run properly?

Comment: No Java to see here -- Java question tag removed

Comment: `var alphabet = [A, B, C, D, E .....` ... should that be `var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' .....`